# How to retain an ip address in sed while changing the netmask?

Tags: sed

I have the following problem: I want to change the netmask of large number of ip adresses in Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` because I am going to expand the network. After changing it I will use `screen ifdown ens18 && ifup ens18` to apply the changes. The substitution of the netmask works in my example, the problem is that I need to keep the 26 unchanged in the ip address. I have a `sed` line which changes all twenty-sixes to 25 but of course this is not what I want.

I have:

```
iface ens18 inet static
    address 195.26.153.26/26
```

I want:

```
iface ens18 inet static
    address 195.26.153.26/25
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To match only the netmask, match it with the separator:

```
sed sX/26X/25X
```

If you’re sure the netmask is at the end of a line, you can constrain the matches further:

```
sed 'sX/26$X/25X'
```